# How to replace apostrophe

Tags: php, python

Here The PHP code.

```
 <?php
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) { ?>
    <?php
        $r = [];
        $f = [];
        $m = [];
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            $r[] = $row['Recency'];
            $f[] = $row['Frequency'];
            $m[] = $row['Monetary'];
            ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['Nama']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Recency']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['Frequency']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo number_format($row['Monetary'], 0, ",", "."); ?></td>
        <tr>
        <?php }
            $recency = implode(',', $r);
            $frequency = implode(',', $f);
            $monetary = implode(',', $m);
            ?>
    <?php }
    ?>
<?php
    echo shell_exec('python C:\\xampp\htdocs\test\try.py "' . $recency . '" "' . $frequency . '" "' . $monetary . '"');
?>
```

Here my try.py code :

```
import sys

q=[[sys.argv[1]],[sys.argv[2]],[sys.argv[3]]]
print (q)
```

I expect the output [[4,3,2],[1,2,3],[9,9,9]], but the actual output is [['4,3,2'],['1,2,3'],['9,9,9']]. How can i replace the ' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

args received as string, so you have to first split them based on `,` and then map the number to `int`

Try with this:

```
q=[map(int, sys.argv[1].split(',')),map(int, sys.argv[2].split(',')),map(int, sys.argv[3].split(','))]
```

For `Python3` `map` will return an map object, so you will have to convert this into `list`

```
q=[list(map(int, sys.argv[1].split(','))),list(map(int, sys.argv[2].split(','))),list(map(int, sys.argv[3].split(',')))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your args are given as strings, so you need to split them first. Then, you can use this simple function to convert all the strings to integers in a nested list:

```
def cast_list(x):
     if isinstance(x, list):
         return list(map(cast_list, x))
     else:
         return int(x)

cast_list([x[0].split(",") for x in [['4,3,2'], ['1,2,3'], ['9,9,9']]])
# [[4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3], [9, 9, 9]]
```